# How to run `forest schema:update` outside project directory?

Tags: forestadmin

I'm trying to use the forest-cli `schema:update` command, but when I do, I keep getting the error:

```
× We are not able to detect a Forest CLI project file architecture at this path: /PATH/TO/REPO/ROOT.: Error: No "routes" directory.
```

There is a `routes` directory, but within `src/` below the repo root. I have tried running `forest schema:update` from inside there, but I get the exact same error. The command only has options for a config file and an output directory.

Googling has turned up nothing, and there's no obvious hint from forestadmin's documents. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Hi, ForestAdmin as a [community forum](https://community.forestadmin.com/latest), I'd take my chances there.

Comment: Thanks, will do

Answer (score 1):

According to the forest-cli code available [here](https://github.com/ForestAdmin/toolbelt), the `forest schema:update` command requires the `package.json` file to be directly accessible in order to run (In the same folder you run the command), to check that the version of the agent you are running is indeed compatible with `schema:update`.

You can also use the `-c/--config` option in order to use another location of your `config/database.js`, and the `-o/--outputDirectory` to output the result to a new location.

In your case, I would say that `forest schema:update -c src/config/database.config.js -o tmp` should allow you to generate the files in the `tmp` directory (Be aware that this directory should not exist).

This command should be run where your `package.json` is located.
However, I don't think you will be able to export files directly at the right location when using a custom folder structure.